# What would be the simplest string value to set DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to figure out the best way of letting the users set the internal DateTime value of the Portable Class Library based on some string parameter they provide. The string parameter has to be a simple format.

So, now I have some considerations.

1. Is specifying UTC Offset enough for getting the right DateTime

   public static DateTime FromUtcOffset(string value)
   {
       var utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
       var offSet = TimeSpan.Parse(value);
       return utcDateTime + offSet;
   }
2. Or is specifying the TimeZone has some advantage over UTC Offset

   ```
   TimeZoneInfo someTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"); 
   DateTime convertTimeFromUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, someTimeZone);
   ```

My question is: What would be the right string parameter that can be taken from the user to let him decide what the value of DateTime would be?

1. Utc Offset
2. TimeZone
3. Or any other alternative that's less verbose.

Comment: What is the question? What does not work?

Comment: So, is it that you have a user and want to present him a select box with some options that define timezone and let him choose the timezone?

Comment: Actually its a class library so I am wondering if the user just provides the UTC Offset will that be enough for setting the internal DateTime of the library or is there any other option that beats this.

Comment: Time zone isn't the same as time offset.Time zone includes more information, for instance, daylight saving time.

Comment: @enkryptor Thank you, that's actually helpful. Will certainly keep that in mind. I now think that going with TimeZone would be the right choice but I unable to find any way in PCL environment that lets me get the DateTime value using some TimeZone ID

Comment: That doesn't mean you must use timezone tho. Normally you use time offset to specify correct time and timezone to find out the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it depends:

1. Do you work with network hosts, located in different time zones
2. Do you store time values for using them in future
3. Does your library work locally (hence, knows user's timezone)

1+2 basically mean if your time offset might change. If it not (the library is intended for local use only), get local time and don't care about the time offset. However, if the offset might change, usually storing "absolute" time in UTC format should be enough. To do this, you can:

1. Ask user for UTC time, not their local time

or

1. Ask for local time + offset (or get the offset from the local time zone, if possible)
2. Convert it to UTC time and store/process in UTC time
3. Provide output using local time (using the offset from 1. if it didn't change)

In 1 and 3 you will need a timezone to figure out the time offset. You don't need to know timezone if you already know the offset. Moreover, DateTime itself can store time offset information. It also can tell you if it stores local or UTC time (see DateTime.Kind Property).

Comment: Thanks! I think pretty much answers my question.